# Wordpress theme customizer jquery not working

Tags: wordpress

i am using jquery inside theme customizer  my requirement is to show a textarea by checking a checkbox.i am using

```
 class Example_Customize_Textarea_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
   public $type = 'textarea';

public function render_content() {
    ?>
        <label>
            <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html($this->label ); ?></span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="c1">        </label>
               <script>
    jQuery(function($){
       // alert();
         $('#customize-control-textarea').hide();
     $('#customize-control-checkbox').click(function(){
    alert();
     });
        // hide control at first load


        // bind to the event that will show the Control

    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
}
```

when i click the checkbox alert is working fine.but the text area is not hidden.i want to show he textarea only the user click on the checkbox. instead of jquery(function($) i use document.ready but it doesn't seems to be working .can anyone show me the right way of doing these